# Is the set of polynomials with only one real root a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm really lost with this question. Could you help me with question (3) and confirm whether question (4) is done right?

Consider the vectorspace $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ of real polynomials:
$$ 
p=a_{0}+a_{1} X+a_{2} X^{2}+\cdots+a_{n-1} X^{n-1}
 $$
of degree $\leq n-1$. Which of the following subset of $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$?.

3) $\{p \in P_{n}(\mathbb{R})|$ p has one real root$\}=C $ 
4) $\{p \in P_{n}(\mathbb{R}) | p(\alpha)=p(-\alpha),$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}=D$

---

I know I have to show, that the zero element is in the subset. That the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

3) My issue here, is I'm not quite sure how to describe all polynomials with only one root. Do these polynomials have something in common, that makes it easier to describe?

4) - (a) Let p=0, bet the zero polynomial.
 We then see:  
$p(\alpha)=0=p(-\alpha)$ - Which means the zero polynomial satisfy the condition and is contained in the set. 
(b) $\operatorname{Let} f, g \in D$ 
$(f+g)(\alpha)=f(\alpha)+g(\alpha)=f(-\alpha)+g(-\alpha)=(f+g)(-\alpha)$ - Which means the sum of two elements also satisfy the condition, and $(f+g) \in D$. 
(c) Let $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ 
$(\gamma f)(\alpha)=\gamma(f(\alpha))=\gamma(f(-\alpha))=(\gamma f)(-\alpha)$
And therefore $(\gamma f) \in D$.

The set D is therefore a subspace of $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: When you add two polynomials, each with only one real root, do you get another such? Think of cubics…

Comment: Polynomials with only one real root are of the form $p(x) = c(x-{\rm root})^k$ for some constant $c\neq 0$ and power $k>0$. If you add two things of that form, do you get something with that same form? Take a guess. :P

Comment: $F(x)=x$ and $G(x)=x^2$ both belong to $C$ but $(F+G)(x)=x+x^2=x(x+1) \not \in C.$  An even simpler example would be that $C$ is not a vector sub-space because $0\not \in C.$

Comment: Your proof that $D$ is a vector subspace is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clear that $C$ is not a subspace, simply because the zero polynomial is not in $C$.